# resteasy cdi producer null

Tags: java, cdi, resteasy, producer

used rest easy and want to manage my entitymanager.
have persistence.xml resources and beans.xml in WEB-INF.
want to use entitymanager in:

```
public class EntityDao {

//    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UserPersistenceUnit")
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void add(Object t) {
        try {
            System.out.println("start adding4.");
            if (entityManager == null) {
                System.out.println("entity manager is null.");
                entityManager = Persistence.
                        createEntityManagerFactory("UserPersistenceUnit").
                        createEntityManager();
                if (entityManager != null) {
                    System.out.println("entity manager created.");
                }
            }
//            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
//            entityManager.persist(t);
//            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

and my producer is:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {

//    @PersistenceContext
//    @Produces
//    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        System.out.println("get enrity manager.");
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.
                createEntityManagerFactory("UserPersistenceUnit").
                createEntityManager();

        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

but my entity manager is null.
anyone can help?

my rest code is:

```
@Path("/userreg")
public class UserRegistration {

    User user;

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public User UserRegister() {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        user = new User();
        user.setUserName("u1");
        user.setPassword("p1");
        userDao.add(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

and UserDao is:

```
public class UserDao extends EntityDao{

}
```

my pom is :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

in EntityDao my EntityManager that has @Inject is null and producer dont work.
thankful.

Comment: What is your application server?  Did you put the persistence.xml file in META-INF? Do you see the system.out message in your producer on your console?

Comment: no idont see my sout in console. app server is wildfly. persistence is in resources/META-INF folder.

Comment: I suppose it's Wildfly 8.2.0... could you put the content of your beans.xml? Also your question is obviously not related to Resteasy. You should perhaps correct the title, tags and content

Comment: but im use this injection in rest class.
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>'

Comment: and yes. its wildfly 8.2.0 .

Comment: look at your code, there's no jax-rs annotation or code. so could you edit your question and put the actual class containing your injection point

Comment: edited. but my injection point is EntityManager in EntityDao.

Comment: You should not be instantiating the DAO yourself.

Comment: very thanks. problem is this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here

```
UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
```

If you instantiate the class by yourself with a `new`, it won't be managed by CDI and thus `@Inject` will be ignored  and your field will be empty.

So the correct code would be:

```
@Path("/userreg")
public class UserRegistration {

    User user;

    @Inject
    UserDao userDao;

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public User UserRegister() {
        user = new User();
        user.setUserName("u1");
        user.setPassword("p1");
        userDao.add(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Beyond that, a little feedback on your code:

1. check that the `@Produces` in `Resources` is the
   `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` and not `javax.ws.rs.Produces`,
   your IDE could play you a bad trick if you don't check the import
   section
2. I'd advise you to uncomment the `@PersistenceContext` part of your code. Avoid to generate it by hand in a Java EE application: you'll loose a lot of out of the box feature of Java EE.
3. You shouldn't add an hibernate dependency included in your peoject since it's provided by WildFly.